# Cosmos DB Failed loading emulator certificate

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I install Cosmos DB, I meet an error:

> "Failed loading emulator certificate"

Please see the picture below. Can someone help me solve this issue?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by install cosmosdb?

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this problem today. You can solve this by deleting the two certificates "CosmosEmulatorSecrets" and "DocumentDbEmulatorCertificate", both issued to localhost. They are under Certificates - Local Computer>Personal>Certificates in mmc, or you can look for them in the certificate manager.