# Azure CosmosDb Emulator Error: Failed loading emulator secrets certificate

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I installed Azure CosmosDb Emulator but it does not start and gives error:
"Failed loading emulator secrets certificate. Error: 0x80092022"
When I check my certificates, it also does not create any certificates related to cosmos db emulator. Then, I tried to create the certificates manually by "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /GenCert" command on cmd but this time show the error "Error generating Emulator SSL certificates"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this link help? [Cosmos DB Failed loading emulator certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483489/cosmos-db-failed-loading-emulator-certificate)

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue I am actively troubleshooting as well. The way to generate the *missing* certificates is to do the following:

1. Open cmd.exe with Administrator
2. Navigate to CosmosDB Install folder with this command

   `C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator`
3. Run this command to ensure the CosmosDB Emulator is shutdown

   `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /Shutdown`
4. Run this command to generate the missing certificates:

   `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /GenCert`
5. Ensure the following certificate correctly generated in Computer Certificates under **Local Computer\Personal\Certificates**

   `DocumentDbEmulatorCertificate | LocalHost`
6. Start CosmosDB from either the start menu or command line and wait for it to fully initialize